# Bug in appending CSV file by write.table?

Tags: csv, write.table

I am running some simulations using R, which at the very end produce a matrix with the outcome. Since I run it under different conditions, I use *append* in the *write.table* command which writes it into a CSV file.

For a while, everything seemed to work fine. But then yesterday, something in the output CSV file seemed wrong: the order of the simulations was upside down, and one column looked unrealistic. Additionally, the column title written underneath the troublesome column got a "3" instead of the column name.

Since this was the result of the last simulation, and hence was still saved in the last matrix created, I could check it. The first columns of the output were fine, but then there was lack of correspondence between the last two columns in the file and the real output.

Writing the matrix into a file is the very last command on my program. Here is the command I use:

```
write.table(gen.dist, "FST2.csv", col.names=TRUE, row.names=F,sep=",", append=T)
```

gen.dist is a numeric matrix.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?
Thank you

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Hi,
I am using R. I added it above. Thank you